# How to make Azure Bash CLI commands as parameters based?

Tags: azure-cli

Azure CLI command should be Parameters based, so that user can enter his any values to parameters and deployment should be proceed.any one know how to set this parameter.

example- I want to create one azure resource group and the value is user-defined.

az group create --name "user-defined" --location "East US 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, you could use [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/Read-Host?view=powershell-7) to promote user to input the parameter value.

```
$groupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your group  name'
az group create --name $groupName --location "East US 2"
```

[image]

In Linux, you could use [`read -p`](https://medium.com/@blackode/read-command-linux-shell-ee84a45591f5) to promote user to input the parameter value.

```
read -p "Enter your groupname: " myname
az group create --name $myname --location "East US 2"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. How can we run an existing CLI script file in Azure Bash?

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-execute-sh-shell-script/) to run cli script file.